# My daughters half brother shows up as 15.4%

Tags: 23andme, half-siblings

My family did 23 and me, my daughter and her 1/2 brother show up as only 15.4%. They’re dad also did one and it shows he is the father of both kids. How is this possible?

Comment: What are their shared cMs? If you know that, you can use the DNA Painter <https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4> tool to see what range of shared DNA would be considered normal for half-siblings and other relationships.